# PHP typed class members array of string

Tags: php, strict

What is the proper syntax to declare a type string[] attribute in php?

```
protected string[] $array_of_strings;
```

does gives an error at '['

Comment: PHP doesn’t have such syntax. You can use `@return string[]` in a docblock if you need an IDE to pick it up

Comment: @Clive In this case, it's a property, not a function return type, so it would be `@var string[]`

Comment: Side note: this is a "[property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)"; in PHP 8, there is a completely separate thing called an "[attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php)", so you may confuse people if you use the wrong term.

Comment: Bruh I was finishing my answer when this got closed! you can only do `protected array $array_of_strings;` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.typed-properties https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.base

Answer (score -2):

You can also use like:

$Array = ["foo","bar", "value"];